# Webpack throws POSTCSS wrong configuration errors

Tags: webpack, postcss, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm trying to update to webpack 2 and I'm stuck in post css loading phase. Here's my relevant code:

```
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceComments=true'}),
      exclude: /\/custom-apps\/|future/
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]&importLoaders=2!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceComments=true',
      include: /\/custom-apps\/|future/
    },
```

The error I get:

`PostCSS Config could not be loaded. Please check your PostCSS Config.`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a local file at project root path

`postcss.config.js`

with content:

```
module.exports = {
  importLoaders: 1,
};
```

did it for me.

Also putting 
`!postcss-loader?importLoaders: 1` in my example code I think should work.